# VBA Looping through multiple worksheets, getting End If w/o block error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a function that loops through 40 worksheets and adds the values in the worksheets that are between two dates. When I run the function I get an "End If without Block If" error. When I delete the last End If then I get an "invalid next control variable reference" error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Function addIntPrinc(beginDate, endDate)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim finalRow As Long, I As Long, intPrinc As Double
intPrinc = 0
finalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Loan *#" Then
        For I = 25 To finalRow
        If Cells(I, 2) >= beginDate And Cells(I, 2) < endDate Then
            intPrinc = intPrinc + Cells(I, 3).Value
        End If
    End If
Next ws
End Function

addIntPrinc = intPrinc
```

Comment: You're missing a `Next i` before the second `End If`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `Next` statement on your 2nd For loop

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Loan *#" Then
        For I = 25 To finalRow
             If Cells(I, 2) >= beginDate And Cells(I, 2) < endDate Then
                 intPrinc = intPrinc + Cells(I, 3).Value
            End If
        Next '***New Line
    End If
Next ws
```